# Referencing a XSD schema within jar file

Tags: java, jar, xsd

I have two schema files one is imported from the other.  When executing the code in Eclipse schemas are found but when executing the code from jar schema files are not found

here is the code

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        factory.setValidating(false);

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
                .newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        try {
            factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new Source[] {
                    new StreamSource(getClass().getResource("Liso.xsd")
                            .getFile()),
                    new StreamSource(getClass().getResource("LisoXml.xsd")
                            .getFile()) }));
                this.saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        } catch (SAXException se) {
            System.out.println("SCHEMA : " + se.getMessage()); // problem in the XSD itself
        }
```

and here is the error I get

```
SCHEMA : schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/C:/Tools/lib/LisoTools.jar!/com/xerox/liso/xml/Liso.xsd', because 1) could not find the do
cument; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Thanks

Comment: I remember that I had a similiar issue two years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065868/need-help-with-strange-classgetresource-issue - `getRessource()` worked with java 1.4.2 but not with java 1.6 ...

Comment: Verify you jar has `/com/xerox/liso/xml/Liso.xsd` included and it looks like an xsd, as well :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If `Liso.xsd` is importing `LisoXml.xsd`, then it is just sufficient to define `Liso.xsd` to the schema factory as shown below. The api is smart enough the load the imported/included schema(s).

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
Schema compiledSchema = schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Liso.xsd"))
```

I verified this worked on both 1.5 and 1.6. On 1.6, you might hit in to [this issue](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/spericas/archive/2007/03/xml_schema_vali.html) as well if using DOM.

Comment: Both above links are dead. :-(

Comment: Hello Aravind, i ran into the same issue. The p

Comment: I get

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical
        at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:420)
...`