# How do I validate an XML with a schema file that imports another schema file?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, moxy, xsd-validation

I want to validate XML files against [this schema](http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/generalinvoicerequest_430.xsd.zip) (that is inside the zip); it imports two other XSD files.

```
   <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
       schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
   <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" 
       schemaLocation="xenc-schema.xsd"/>
```

The 2 files are also available here:

- http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/xmldsig-core-schema.zip
- http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/xenc-schema.zip.

On validation, I get this error:

```
Src-resolve: Cannot Resolve The Name 'xenc:EncryptedData' To A(n) 'element Declaration' Component.
```

My validation/unmarshalling code looks like this (using moxy as a JAXB provider):

```
jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(type.getRequestType().getPackage().getName());
Unmarshaller um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/xsd/" + type.getXsdName())));
um.setSchema(schema);

root = um.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlData)), type.getRequestType());
```

Before you ask what does the type do: I wrote code that could import all types of invoices from http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/. But versions 4.3 and above use the two additional schema files. How can validate the XML files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the accepted answer for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280226/referencing-a-xsd-schema-within-jar-file). Based on the little I can see in your post, and from what I can remember, the problem with the way you're loading the XSD has to do with the fact that doing it your way, the factory doesn't get a base uri, hence it can't apply its smarts to resolve references to the other two XSDs. I have to assume that your other two XSDs are also packed as resources in the same jar, in the same directory.

I have to admit that I am intrigued by the error message, which seems to imply the schema it loaded is valid, so it might be an XML issue; if the above doesn't help you, then you should consider posting the offending XML as well...

UPDATE: As per my comments, it is working as described. See code snippet below:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
Schema compiledSchema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new SOTests().getClass()
    .getClassLoader().getResource("generalInvoiceRequest_430.xsd"));
Validator validator = compiledSchema.newValidator();
try {
    validator.validate(new StreamSource("D:\\...\\dentist_ersred_TG_430.xml"));
    System.out.println("Valid.");
}
catch (SAXException ex) {
    System.out.print("Not valid because..." + ex.getMessage());
}
```

You don't need to load more than the first XSD, and you shouldn't, since all the imports provide hints to the schema location.

[image]

The XSD files are **all** in the same directory in the generated jar, and they must be, since the relative URIs used for imports indicate same parent.

[image]

The program output with one of the files downloaded from [here](http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/xmlstandards_generelle_rechnung_beispiele_anfrage_4.3_20100901.zip):

```
Valid.
```

And after introducing invalid content:

```
Not valid because...cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'wrong'. One of '{"http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/invoice":processing}' is expected.
```

My recommendations to who reads this:

- use getResource() to get an URL; as I've said above, a StreamResource doesn't have a base URI, hence relative references as per your xsd:import schemaLocation attribute cannot be de-referenced.
- Let the schema/factory do the loading for you, when they're explicitly provided.
- make sure that when provided, relative references match the folder structure in your jar file.

Comment: both the xsds and the xmls are given and both are from the same "official" source http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/. So it is most likely no problem in xsd or xml.
But in the post you referenced i see that schema factory could take more than one xsd - i think that's the solution. i'll try.

Comment: i just tried to load all schemas in schema factory but the error persists. On the other hand if i try to validate the xml online i got the same error - so i don't know if schemas were loaded and used correctly?!

Comment: @dermoritz, did you try exactly the way described in the post, and did you put *all* the XSDs in the same folder in your jar?

Comment: yeah - but as i stated in my answer: the cause of the problem was the order in which the schemes are added to the array.

Comment: @dermoritz, I've tried it and it works as previously described; I've updated my response with the exact code I've used to test...

Comment: ok i got it: the problem was i used "getResourceAsStream" (works only if loaded all schema in correct order) instead of getResource - this works as you described. probably it would be good to underline "Use getResource" and don't use "getResourceAsStream" - thx!

Answer (score -1):

Similar problems here. I tried to import the `GeneralInvoice` into an integration Software.

1. Parser didn't like the DOCTYPE tag at the start of the import schemas. Solution: deleted the `DOCTYPE` section.
2. Parser didn't lke anyAttribute, anyURI etc. Solution: changed anyURI to string and removed other stuff by putting comments around.
3. Had to import the xenc and xwldsig xsd's first and then import GeneralInvoice in a second step.

Hope this helps