# xsd file in resource folder not able to access on cloud environment with fileResource.getFile()which runs fine for local

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to access xsd in resource folder for eg. `resource/xyz/abc/data.xsd` in spring boot application using below code,

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

...

final Resource fileResource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:XYZ/view/abc.xsd");

fileResource.getFile()
```

Which runs or access xsd file in resource folder properly when I run the application locally same is not happening for test environment which is in cloud
Does anyone has any idea what would be the reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get files from resources folder. Spring Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36407575/how-to-get-files-from-resources-folder-spring-framework)

Comment: To me it should not be the same as whatever code is written is working properly on local machine but same is not working for test environment which is in cloud

Comment: Because it isn't a file anymore. When running locally you are probably running the main boot app from your IDE. Which makes the file accessible as file (as it isn't packaged as a jar). When packaged as a jar it cannot be retrieved as a `File` anymore you can only read it with an `InputStream`. The same will happen locally if you run with `java -jar your-app.jar`.

Comment: The link mentioned has exact solution for the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280226/referencing-a-xsd-schema-within-jar-file